# Ubuntu swap partition missing in windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, swap

I just installed ubuntu as my first linux experience. I've did some research beforehand, and read about swap memory increasing performance. I have data parition (D:/) where I keep all my data, and that one also had the most free space. so I selected that one. I did NOT select the format option.

I'm currently on windows 7, and I can only see my C:/ partition, which has windows stored on it.

Did I just erased all the data on my D:/ paritition? :(

I can't check on ubuntu if the data is there because Ubuntu is missing from the boot options. I actually have no idea how to get in there.

Comment: I have now added the ubuntu boot option using easyBCD. The swap partition is nowhere to be found though :(

Comment: DO NOT START Ubuntu ! If you start it some writing to swap could destroy former contents of D: partition AND IT CANNOT BE RECOVERED !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about 40 hours of googeling and experimenting I found that the solution was a simple as this:

- start testdisk from ubuntu
- select your drive (usually the default - intel)
- select "Advanced"

---

In case you do not get the "List" option:

- select the swap partition, and at the bottom menu select "Type"
- press enter and enter " 7"  when it asks for the type (original should be 82)
- DO NOT REBOOT, even if it tells you to (messed up alot of stuff for me)

---

- repeat step 1 tot 2, but now select "List"
- search for the files you want to backup, press C and select the directory that you want to copy to (has to be on a different partition)

Unfortunately after all the previous messing with partitions I have lost literally every file that I was hoping to get back. But it still seems I have about 60% left of everything else.
I still have an image from ddrescue that might be my final hope.

Comment: +1  Great Link.  You can try mounting the .dd image with [OSFMount](http://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/Virtual-CD-DVD-Rom/OSFMount.shtml) in Windows.

Comment: Yes I tried, but unfortunately the created drive is not accessable

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to recover a partition as you have not used Ubuntu (and swap) yet.

Search on the internet for "partition recovery software".

I think TestDisk is one of the best tools available but it needs some knowledge on disk structure, partitions, (logical, primary), partition addressing, formating - not a point and click task.

You can try also MiniTool Partition Recovery - a GUI tool more user friendly but not so advanced as TestDisk.

Read manual of whatever tool you will use before atempting repairs !

If unsure DO NOT WRITE CHANGES TO DISK ! Ask again for help on forum.

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea where/who told you that Swap increases performance, it does not. It's used for the same purpose Virtual memory is used in Windows, you run out of RAM Swap is used, you want to Hibernate/Suspend Swap is used.

If you did selected your D:/ partition to be used as Swap, then it's simply gone.